# Difference between Swift 2 and 3? How to all a class's method within another?

Tags: ios, swift, class, methods

I believe I have a pretty simple question here, but due to my lack of experience with Swift, I have been unable to find the answer.

Here are two classes I created:

My controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private weak var display: UILabel!

    private var userIsInTheMIddleOfTyping = false

    private var brain  = CalculatorBrain()

    private var displayValue: Double {

    get {

        return Double(display.text!)!

    }

    set {

        display.text = String(newValue)

    }

    }


    @IBAction private func performOperation(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if userIsInTheMIddleOfTyping{

            brain.setOperand(displayValue)

            userIsInTheMIddleOfTyping = false

        }

        if let mathematicalSymbol = sender.currentTitle {

            brain.performOperation(mathematicalSymbol)

        }

        displayValue = brain.result

        }

    }
```

My model:

```
import Foundation

class CalculatorBrain{

    private var accumulator = 0.0

    func  setOperand(operand: Double){

        accumulator = operand

    }

    func performOperation(symbol: String){

        switch symbol{

            case "π": accumulator = M_PI

            case "√": accumulator = sqrt(accumulator)

            default: break
        }

    }

    var result: Double{

        get {

            return accumulator
        }

    }

}
```

For some reason I get an error in line: `brain.setOperand(displayValue)`

Any reason why?

Comment: Where does `displayValue` come from?

Comment: Sorry! Updated to include 'displayValue'

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: It says `brain.setOperand(displayValue)` should be `brain.setOperand(operand: displayValue)`, but once I do that, the app still crashes.

Comment: If the app crashes, update your question with the precise error message.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and everything was fine, excepted two things:

```
brain.setOperand(operand: displayValue)
brain.performOperation(symbol: mathematicalSymbol)
```

In Swift 3, the first parameter need a external parameter by default.